# Unicode BIDI (UBA): R RLI R; Why should RLI stay on level 0

Tags: unicode, bidi

implementing isolater logic for the BIDI got me stuck again. Given the following test case.

```
@Levels: 1 0 1
@Reorder: 0 1 2
R  RLI  R ; 2  # LTR flag
\____/ \_/ (my run sequences)
```

Here is my current understanding:

After processing *rules X1-X8* you end up with levels `0 0 1` which will convert to two isolated run sequences.

As far as I can tell, *rules W1-W7* should not apply to any characters.

*Rule N1* however will raise the level of the `RLI` to 1 as it is an `NI` between two strong types, the `R` and the `eos` of the first sequence.

*Rule I1/2* will then push the first `R` to level 1.

*Rule L1* could lower the level of an RLI but does not apply here.

How is that, that the RLI should end up on level 0.

---

Same problem with similar tests, just invthe opposite direction.

```
@Levels: 2 1 2
@Reorder: 2 1 0
L LRI L; 4
```

Sadly http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/bidi.jsp does not implement the latest algorithm including the RLI/LRI.

Any advice welcome :) thank you.

Comment: Further checking, I think I am computing the eos wrong. Considering X10 note "...and if there is none or the last character of the sequence is an isolate initiator (lacking a matching PDI), with the paragraph embedding level."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the issue was that *Rule N1* should not have been applied since the `eos` is of type `L` and not `R`.

I have missed the Note at X10 stating that: ...and if there is none or the last character of the sequence is an isolate initiator (lacking a matching PDI), with the paragraph embedding level."